# Codeblocks C++ project won't build or run

Tags: 14.04, c++, compiler, code-blocks

I am a new Ubuntu user. I started C++ programming in Windows using Code::Blocks, and would like to try the open source environment of Linux.

I am looking to set up Code::Blocks IDE to develop in C++. I have installed it and used it to create my first hello world application in Ubuntu. I tried to compile and run it, but it has a debugger issue and what appears to be a link issue. When I first started the first C++ test.cpp project, it asked me what compiler to use, and it automatically detected the GNU GCC Compiler which I selected.

Do I need to download anything from the repository to get my C++ code to run in Code::Blocks? Do I need to link anything in my build options that isn't done automatically?

Comment: I upvoted and favorited this because I need to know how Codeblocks and g++ configured properly to suite DevC++ in Ubuntu.

Comment: yea i wish i could get some solid advice. everything I found isn't enough

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ program is not running in Code::Blocks because you do not have a C++ compiler (a version of G++) installed, or if it is installed you have not configured the C++ compiler in the Code::Blocks compiler settings. The C++ compiler is not configured for any version of g++ by default, so it has to be configured in the Code::Blocks compiler settings.

1. Install the g++ compiler for C++

   ```
   sudo apt install g++ xterm
   ```

   Optionally install gcc too if it is not already installed.

   ```
   sudo apt install gcc
   ```
2. Start Code::Blocks.
3. Select *Settings* -> *Compiler* -> *Global compiler settings* (large blue gear icon in the left pane) -> *Toolchain executables* tab.
4. Select the *Program Files* tab. It has already been selected in the below screenshot.
5. Click the **<kbd>..</kbd>** button(s) which are marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot. Navigate to `/usr/bin`. The *C compiler* should be `gcc`, the *C++ compiler* should be `g++` and the *Linker for dynamic libs* should be `g++`.
6. Click the     **<kbd>OK</kbd>**     button to close the **Compiler settings** window.

*Note:* It is permissible to install later versions of gcc and g++ from the default Ubuntu repositories alongside gcc and g++ and select them instead of gcc and g++ in the Code::Blocks compiler settings. The latest versions of gcc and g++ in 19.10 and 20.04 are gcc-9 and g++-9.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `Code::Blocks` doesn't require any additional configuration.
You should have installed `g++` package. You can do it by issuing command

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```